# Sort unordered SQL results based on the original Array order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I send an Array of IDs into a controller `params[:ids] = [2,5,9,...]`

Now if I perform a Query like `Device.find(params[:ids])` the results are sorted based on the Database. How can I sort the result based on the original Array, so the Device with the id 2 comes first etc.?

Comment: @toro2k This is no duplicate. Using Ruby is not the only way for ordered SQL results.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You could look up the `id`'s index with [`Array#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-index):

```
ids = params[:ids]
Device.find(ids).sort_by { |device| ids.index(device.id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just by using SQL:

```
Device.where(params[:ids]).order("field(id, #{params[:ids].map(:to_i).join(',')})")
```

This will be faster than doing it with Ruby.

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: On which DBMS the function `field` works? I've tried on postgres and sqlite but neither define it.

Comment: I am using MySql. Using that throws me a `undefined method .order` error. I guess I have to use `:order =>` inside find instead?

Comment: @Nikom What is the actual error? Can you try now with the updated answer?